Add a specific field for licence / copyright notice
In the standard article class. How can I add a specific field for copyright notice below the Title, subtitle, author, and date ?
The goal would be to have a command like so \copyright{} and that would put it below the date on the first page of the document.

You need to change the title page to place additional things there. Please show a minimal working example so that we can see which packages and document class you are actually working with.

\copyright already exists to make just the copyrignt symbol.  Guessing that you use  \maketitle instead of a title page, it could be as simple as adding \vspace{-1em}{\centering\copyright\space Louis \the\year\par} after that command. Otherwise, add the MWE, as requested.

Copyright or license as an alternative. But a field like so should be made a default field for all documents.

For the article class you can modify \@maketitle (which is called by \maketitle) to include a macro \@copyright. This can be defined in the same way as for example \author or \date, which are simple macros that store their argument in corresponding @-version:
\def\copyright#1{\gdef\@copyright{© #1}}

Note that this is a bad idea because the macro \copyright already exists in LaTeX to typeset the © symbol. This definition overwrites the original macro so if you want that symbol (or if in any of the code \copyright is used with the expectation that it has the original definition) then you need to use alternatives, for example including © directly in the source.
It might be a good idea to include a default value not to get errors when somebody doesn't include the \copyright declaration. Even nicer would be to check if it is defined and don't allocate space in the title block when there is no definition, but that is left as an exercise :)
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@copyright{I'm free!} % default value
\def\copyright#1{\gdef\@copyright{© #1}}
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage \null \vskip 2em\begin {center}\let \footnote \thanks {\LARGE \@title \par }\vskip 1.5em{\large \lineskip .5em\begin {tabular}[t]{c}\@author \end {tabular}\par }\vskip 1em{\large \@date }\vskip 1em \@copyright\end {center}\par \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\author{Alice Smith}
\title{On Copyright}
\date{\today}
\copyright{Alice Inc.}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Copyright is the right to copy
\end{abstract}
\section{History}
Before copyright existed copying was impossible.
\end{document}



Thanks ! I’ll see what I can do with the exercise ;)
